# DC motor free spin

Tags: dc-motor

I have a DC motor connected to a roller. The roller is rotated by a load.
If I don't power supply the motor, it will free spin.
Then I would like to turn on the motor only on certain times, to help the spinning. 
Could this be done or it damages the motor?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the motor as you describe, without damaging the motor. The load spinning the motor will generate a voltage at the motor terminals (it will act as a generator) so make sure that whatever it is connected to will withstand this voltage - if there is a load on the motor it will act as a brake.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks. What do you mean with "if there is a load on the motor it will act as a brake"?

Comment: It will be harder to turn the motor if it is supplying current. Motors act as generators when they are used like this, so if you put a load on the generator, the power the load uses must come from somewhere, hence it is harder to turn the motor when it has a load. Try spinning a DC motor without its terminals connected, then try again with its terminals shorted - the difference is quite surprising.

Comment: ok, I have to perform some tests... thank you Icy!